# How do I implement a simple multithreaded FileLogger in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In order to learn about multithreading programming in C++ I am implementing a basic multithreaded logger.

I use a std::deque to store messages inside a FileLogger class. 
Each time a thread logs a message; that message is pushed to the back of the deque.

In a separate thread the FileLogger checks if there are any messages in the deque and if so writes them to file.

Access to the deque is guarded by a mutex.

In order to make it easy to log from anywhere; the logger is implemented as a singleton.

**Since the instance is a (static) pointer, and the pointer do not change; the instance does not have to be guarded by a mutex?**

**Is my code correct?**

```
// FileLogger.h:
class FileLogger
{
public:
    static void initialize(const char* filePath) { // called by main thread before any threads are spawned
        instance_ = new FileLogger(filePath);
    }
    static FileLogger* instance() { // called from many threads simultaneously
        return instance_;
    }
    void log(const std::string &msg);
private:
    FileLogger(const char* filePath);
    void writeToFile();
    static FileLogger*     instance_;
    std::deque<std::string> messages;
    std::mutex         messagesMutex; // lock/unlock this each time messages is pushed or popped
    std::ofstream               fout;
    std::thread         writerThread;
};
// FileLogger.cpp:
FileLogger* FileLogger::instance_ = nullptr;

void FileLogger::writeToFile() {
    for (;;) {
        std::string message;
        while (messages.empty()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(10));
        }
        messagesMutex.lock();
        message = messages.front();
        messages.pop_front();
        messagesMutex.unlock();
        fout << message << std::endl << std::flush;
    }
}

FileLogger::FileLogger(const char* filePath) {
    fout.open(filePath);
    std::thread t(&FileLogger::writeToFile, this);
    writerThread = std::move(t);
}

void FileLogger::log(const std::string &msg) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(messagesMutex);
    messages.push_back(msg);
}
```

Comment: The best way don't do it yourself. There are many ready solution which will be faster safer then thing you will write. Try for example [boost::log](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @MarekR OP said it is for learning purposes. As for the question, it is more suited for code review [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Logger is not best choice learn MT programming.

Comment: Please do get a code review! The small amount of working code is perfect for such things. I restricted my answer below to your actual question only, even though there are a few things that could be improved.

Comment: Thank you! I have posted on code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238234/how-do-i-implement-a-simple-multithreaded-filelogger-in-c

Comment: "Multi-threaded?" or "thread-safe?" A multi-threaded module would be a module that uses multiple threads for its own purpose. A thread-safe module is one that is designed to be called from more than one thread in the same program.

Comment: @Solomon: I think maybe both? The logger has to be thread-safe but it also runs its own thread. Even if it is being run from the main thread it introduces another thread ->multi-threaded?

Comment: I was asking more about the requirements than about any particular implementation (e.g., the implementation that you show in the question.) Whether or not it actually is necessary to do the writes in a dedicated, background thread might depend on whether the `fout` stream itself is thread safe, on how long any given write to it could take, and on the latency requirements of other threads in the program. In some cases, it might be adequate to simply have the calling thread directly write the stream after locking a _fair_ mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following assumptions (reduction of your code):

- There is a pointer (the one holding your singleton).
- This pointer is only set once and remains constant after that.
- Further threads are started only after the pointer is set.

In that case, you don't have to sync access to the pointer itself. The starting of a thread serves as synchronization already: All writes that happen before starting the thread are visible to the code running inside the thread.